# Get-ADUser error, Name is not a parameter for filter

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script to get administrators account details from the Active Directory but I am encountering this error. Sorry Im quite new to PowerShell.

Get-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Object[]
Parameter name:name
At line:1 char:1

- GetADUser -Filter {Name -eq $Admin} -Properties * | Select-Object DisplayName, ...
- CategoryInfo    : Invalid Argument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

The following is my script:

```
PROCESS{
$path = Split-Path -parent "$CSVReportPath\*.*" 
$pathexist = Test-Path -Path $path 
If ($pathexist -eq $false) 
{New-Item -type directory -Path $path} 
 
$reportdate = Get-Date -Format ddmmyyyy 

$csvreportfile = $path + "\ALLADUsers_$reportdate.csv" 

$Admin = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Administrators | select-object Name

Foreach( $i in $Admin){
 Get-ADUser  -Filter {Name -eq $Admin} -Properties * | select-object DisplayName, samaccountName, Enabled, 
 Created, LastLogonDate | sort-object -Property LastLogonDate |
  }
  Export-Csv -Path $csvreportfile -NoTypeInformation     
 }
```

Comment: Sorry i put an older version of the script

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error, but now it says the search filter cannot be recognized

Comment: Yes i typed it in but it still shows the error

Comment: Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$i` as that's the variable you declared foreach item in `$Admin`. Next, use double quotes for the filter and single quotes around the variable.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$i'" -Properties *
```